# MYSQL : WHERE IN and OR are not returning the same rows

Tags: mysql, sql, where-in

i'm new to mysql and playing with sakila database. Can anyone hint as to why these to queries do not return the exact same rows?

IF i use a sequence of OR statements:

```
mysql> use sakila
Database changed
mysql> SELECT first_name,last_name,address.city_id FROM customer
    -> JOIN store ON store.store_id=customer.store_id
    -> JOIN address ON customer.address_id=address.address_id
    -> WHERE store.store_id=1 AND address.city_id=1 OR address.city_id=42
    -> OR address.city_id=312 OR address.city_id=459;
+------------+-------------+---------+
| first_name | last_name   | city_id |
+------------+-------------+---------+
| JULIE      | SANCHEZ     |       1 |
| SCOTT      | SHELLEY     |      42 |
| CLINTON    | BUFORD      |      42 |
| MATTIE     | HOFFMAN     |     312 |
| CECIL      | VINES       |     312 |
| NELSON     | CHRISTENSON |     459 |
+------------+-------------+---------+
6 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

IF i use IN ():

```
mysql> SELECT first_name,last_name,address.city_id FROM customer
    -> JOIN store ON store.store_id=customer.store_id
    -> JOIN address ON customer.address_id=address.address_id
    -> WHERE store.store_id=1 AND address.city_id IN (1,42,312,459);
+------------+-------------+---------+
| first_name | last_name   | city_id |
+------------+-------------+---------+
| JULIE      | SANCHEZ     |       1 |
| SCOTT      | SHELLEY     |      42 |
| CECIL      | VINES       |     312 |
| NELSON     | CHRISTENSON |     459 |
+------------+-------------+---------+
4 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

It seems IN() lists only first instance of city_id. Everywhere on the web it's stated that these two scenarios differ ONLY performance-wise. What am i missing?

Comment: You are missing parentheses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enclose `AND` `OR` combinations in `round brackets ()` appropriately in your 1st query.

The clause `WHERE store.store_id=1 AND address.city_id=1 OR address.city_id=42 OR address.city_id=312 OR address.city_id=459` will return all rows with store_id as 1 and city_id as 1 plus all rows with either city_id as 41 or 312 or 459 irrespective of store_id.

Change it to below query and it will return exact same rows as 2nd `IN` query.

```
SELECT first_name,last_name,address.city_id FROM customer
JOIN store ON store.store_id=customer.store_id
JOIN address ON customer.address_id=address.address_id
WHERE store.store_id=1
AND (address.city_id=1
    OR address.city_id=42 
    OR address.city_id=312
    OR address.city_id=459);
```

Comment: Great, thanks Samir! Things become perfectly clear when i SELECT store.store_id as well!

Comment: You may accept my answer so if someone comes up in future it becomes more useful :).

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use parentheses in your query as the AND used in second query only works on two condition's besides it. You should try this

```
SELECT first_name,last_name,address.city_id FROM customer
JOIN store ON store.store_id=customer.store_id
JOIN address ON customer.address_id=address.address_id
WHERE store.store_id=1 AND 
(
    address.city_id = 1
    OR address.city_id = 42 
    OR address.city_id = 312
    OR address.city_id = 459
);
```

After this both of the query return same result.

Answer (score 1):

Replace query with ,

```
mysql> select first_name,last_name,address.city_id from customer
         ->join store on store.store_id=customer.store_id
         -> join address on customer.address_id=address.address_id
         -> where store.store_id=1 and   ( address.city_id = 1  or address.city_id = 42   or address.city_id = 312   or address.city_id = 459 );
```